# MVC 5 Paging a long list (50 000 object), i used listPaged but it takes time to charge list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, pagedlist

I has to display a list of books that containes more than 50 000 book. 
I want to display paged list where for each page i invoke a method that gives me 20 books.

```
List< Books > Ebooks = Books.GetLibrary(index);
```

But using [PagedList](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList) doesnt match with my want because it creates a subset of the  collection of objects given and  accesse to each subset with the index. And refering to the definition of its methode, i had to charge the hole list from the begining.

I also followed [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

```
var EBooks = from b in db.Books select b;
 int pageSize = 20;
 int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

 return View(Ebooks.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

But doing so, i has to invoke (var Books = from b in db.Books select b; ) on each index

**EDIT****

I'm searching for indications to achieve this

List< Books > Ebooks = Books.GetLibrary(index);
and of course i has the number of all the books so i know the number of pages
So i'm  searching for indication that leads me to achieve it: for each index, i invoke  GetLibrary(index)

---

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
var pagedBooks = Books.GetLibrary().Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

This assumes a 0-based pageNumber.

If that doesn't work, can you add a new method to the Books class that gets a paged set directly from the data source?

Something like "Books.GetPage(pageNumber, pageSize);" that way you don't get the entire collection every time.

Other than that, you may have to find a way to cache the initial result of Books.GetLibrary() somewhere.

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes that i what GetLibrary do: it gets the books by pages, 20 book by page and skipping 20*page_number. The pagedList divides the list given, for example if we have 20 books ( result of GetLibrary) , the pagedList( pagenumber, pageSize) : pagesize= books to display on a page and pagenumber the index both retatif to pagedList, so it will divide 20 books by  pageSize and we w'll have 20/pagesize pages

Comment: What i want is that i can every time invoke GetLibrary (index ): index =numbre of books/ 20 books